# Stuck silverware drawer

Tags: drawers

I have a steak knife stuck in a open wire tray.  I can open the drawer about 4", but cannot release the knife that is lodged at the back of the tray.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a kitchen drawer? You should have access to the back of the drawer (closed) by going down underneath through the kitchen cabinet.

Close the drawer and fetch your knife that way.

Answer (score 1):

I actually helped an elderly friend with this problem not long ago. I used a flexable cutting board it was maybe 1/16 inch thick plastic. Slightly opening the drawer and slipping the material in until it hit the spatula in this case pushed it down enough to get my large hand in and remove it even though it was stuck in the wood above.